# Can't declare a 2D dynamic array in a struct

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic, malloc, dynamic-allocation

So I have 2 questions.

I'm trying to learn how to dynamically allocate memory for 2D arrays.
Here is a working code, I first want to know if it's fine, it works but I really don't know if I have memory leaks or some errors I don't see.

```
typedef struct Map Map;

struct Map
{
    int width, height;
    int** cases; // Not technically a 2D array but I use it like it in my code
};

int getMapValue(Map map, int x, int y);
void setMapValue(Map* map, int value, int x, int y);

void mallocMap(Map* map, int width, int height);
void freeMap(Map* map);

int main()
{
    int l,h,i,j;
    Map map;

    printf("Width : ");
    scanf("%d", &l);
    printf("Height : ");
    scanf("%d", &h);

    map.width = l;
    map.height = h;

    mallocMap(&map, l, h); // allocate memory for the map

    for(j = 0; j < map.height; j++)
        for(i = 0; i < map.width; i++)
            setMapValue(&map, i*j, i, j); // set some values

    for(j = 0; j < map.height; j++)
        for(i = 0; i < map.width; i++)
            printf("%d ", getMapValue(map, j, i)); // read some values, works fine

    freeMap(&map); // free memory

    return 0;
}

void mallocMap(Map* map, int width, int height)
{
    map->cases = malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height);

    if (map->cases == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}

void freeMap(Map* map)
{
    free(map->cases);
}

int getMapValue(Map map, int x, int y)
{
    return *(map.cases + y*map.height + x);
}

void setMapValue(Map* map, int value, int x, int y)
{
    *(map->cases + y*map->height + x) = value;
}
```

Then I have a problem.
I want to add a struct Player which has two Map elements in it like so :

```
struct Player
{
    Map map[2];
};
```

But this results in an error `array has incomplete element type`. Apparently it's because of the size of the array that isn't set correctly, how should I make this work ?

Update : I needed to write the Map structure before the Player structure.

Comment: `int** cases; // 2D array` is __not__ a 2d array. It is a pointer to a pointer. An array of pointers at the most.

Comment: I understand, I will change my sentences but it's as if I had a 2d array for me with my `getMapValue` and `setMapValue` which need x and y.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you please show at which position in the coude you define `struct Player`?

Comment: I just set struct Map before struct Player and it works. But I was interested in the comment that got deleted telling me I allocate like a 2d array but in fact use a pointer to pointer. Is it still good or totally bad ?

Comment: `map->cases = malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height);` is wrong.  `map->cases` is a `int **`.  The memory allocated it should be based on `int *`, not `int`.  It appears you want too use `int* cases;`  (1 star).

Comment: `int **cases` is a pointer to a pointer.  So `map->cases = malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height);` is semantically wrong.  You're using `sizeof(int *)` instead of `sizeof(int)`.  You should just make `cases` be `int *` instead of `int **`.  This would be consistent with the rest of your code.

Comment: So does `(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height);` works ?

Comment: @Drakalex Cast is not needed.  Use `map->cases  = malloc(sizeof *(map->cases) * width * height);` and drop coding the type in the allocation.  The type is not needed and its use is error prone.

Comment: @Chux.  Yes, but first change change `cases` from `int **` to `int *`.  This is consistent with the rest of the OP's code.

Comment: @Drakalex: I deleted the answer because the part concerning `typedef Map` was wrong. The 2D-thing is still valid.

Comment: Also, `return *(map.cases + y*map.height + x);` should really be `return *(map.cases + y*map.width + x);`

Comment: @MFisherKDX Thanks I just discovered that when I enter 2 different values for height and width I had big errors and your answer is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the "incomplete type" is very likely because you define `struct Player` before having defined `struct Map`.

Concerning your "2D"-Array: With `map->cases = malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height);`, you actually reserve memory in a layout similar to a "real" 2D-array, whereas datatype `int **cases` denotes a pointer to pointer to an int.
So if you switch to `int *cases`, it should work.

Note that `cases` still is not a "real" 2D-Array, since you are not allowed to access it like `map->cases[3][4]` (this would yield undefined behaviour). But you calculate the offsets on your own in the getter and setter functions anyway, so your implementation should work.

Comment: Which solution do you think is the best one ? I just need a 2d dynamic arrays containing int, I searched online and this was one of the solution but there were many other.

Comment: Both solutions have drawbacks and benefits. Drawback of the `int*`-way is that you cannot access the array in an `[x][y]`-like manner (which would be possible in the `int **`-case when initialized correctly). The `int**`-case, in contrast involves an additional indirection, memory overhead and a more complicated allocation/freeing of memory.

Comment: In your case, as you already use the getters and setters, the `int*`-way is OK, I think.

Answer (score 1):

> I really don't know if I have memory leaks or some errors I don't see.

Yes.  You have some memory problems during the allocation that has been pointed out by @StephanLechner.

Also, you have an arithmetic error that indexes the wrong elements and indexes outside the bounds of your array.  Your `x` value ranges from `0` to `width-1` and your `y` value ranges from `0` to `height-1`.  Each time you increment `y` you are actually moving `width` elements in the array.  So:

```
return *(map.cases + y*map.height + x);
```

Should be:

```
return *(map.cases + y*map.width + x);
```